# Assign value to newly created variable

Tags: r

I am trying to assign an existing column value to a newly generated column in R. These values are being called by a for loop.
MY data looks  like :

[image]

I created three new columns as follows

```
    for(i in 1:3) {                                        
      
      new1 <- rep(i, nrow(mydata))                            
      mydata[ , ncol(mydata) + 1] <- new1           
      colnames(mydata)[ncol(mydata)] <- paste0("newcol", i)  
      
**paste0("mydata$newcol",i) <- paste0("mydata$Column",i)**
}
```

Now I need to assign newcol0 <- column0, newcol1 <- column1 and so on.

But if I am trying to do the same inside loop with a highlighted code line, I am not able to get the value assigned. I tried other functions as well but no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Closing bracket is after highlighted line of code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
mydata=data.frame(a=1,b=2,c=3,column0=4,column1=5,column2=6)

for(i in 1:3) {                                        
  
  new1 <- rep(i, nrow(mydata))                            
  mydata[ , ncol(mydata) + 1] <- new1           
  colnames(mydata)[ncol(mydata)] <- paste0("newcol", i)  
  as <- mydata[,i+3]
  newcol <- paste0("newcol",i) 
  mydata[,newcol] <- as
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked for 3 but not in case if we have some variable value like.. For ( I in 1: N){} where N is a variable E.g 50.. Note. We have same no.of column(N) as well.